# Magento 2.2 Address Information not showing in admin > sales > order

Tags: paypal, magento2.2

I have setup Magento 2.2 and configure the payment method to "PayPal Express Checkout"

> When i have payment with **PayPal Express Checkout**

Checkout and Payment is working fine but when i go to **Admin > sales > order > edit new order**- in order **Address Information** is not display. Please check below image

[image]

Same issues i have found in order email.

> When i have payment with **Check / Money order**

Every thing working fine.

**NOTE:** i have not installed any third party module and not done any customization. i have test this in 3 setup of Magento 2.2 and all have same issues

Also i have try https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/5873 but not success

Answer (score 0):

This was Magento product issue.. Which is fixed in Magento 2.2.3 version